PDBox signing a document with a cmsSignature
Im trying to sign pdf documents using PdfBox and a cmsSignature.
But my code always return a pdf with a corrupted signature "document has been altered or corruupted since it was signed"
Im using PdfBox 2.0.29
i need the signature to be added to the pdf and the signature to be valid, is it possible?
public ResponseEntity<String>signPdf(@RequestParam String pdfPath,@RequestParam String cmsSignature64){
    try{
        //DecodeCMSsignaturefromBase64
        byte[] cmsSignature=java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(cmsSignature64);
        
        //LoadthePDFdocument
        Path pdfFilePath=Path.of(pdfPath);
        if(!Files.exists(pdfFilePath)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("PDFfilenotfoundat:"+pdfPath);
        }
        
        File inputFile=pdfFilePath.toFile();
        PDDocument document=PDDocument.load(inputFile);
        
        //Createanewsignature
        PDSignature signature=new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setReason("QualifiedCertification");
        signature.setLocation("");
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        signature.setContents(newbyte[8192]);
        
        //Addthesignaturefieldwithaspecificname
        signature.setName("DetachedSignature");
        document.addSignature(signature);
        
        //Prepare the external signature
        ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning=document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(new FileOutputStream(inputFile));
        
        //Write the detached CMSsignature to the PDF
        externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
        
        //Save and close the document
        document.close();
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok("PDF signed successfully:"+pdfFilePath.toString());
    }catch(Exceptione){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("Error while signingPDF:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}


welcome to stackoverflow Rui. did you lose some spacing on the code? i mean returnResponseEntity.badRequest().body(..) doesn't look right.

What does the cmsSignature64 (you retrieve as parameter) sign? After all, your code prepares the PDF for signing, and only after that preparation you know the data to sign...

corrected the loss of spacing

the cmsSignature64 is the digitalsignature of the original pdf, so im just suposed to unite the two

For signing a document you need the private key which is not included in a signed document.

"the cmsSignature64 is the digitalsignature of the original pdf, so im just suposed to unite the two" - then whoever asked you to do this does not understand PDF signing. Just like @KJ explains, the original PDF first must be prepared for signing (adding a signature field if there is no empty one yet, adding a value dictionary for the field with a placeholder for the signature container to embed, optionally some signature visualization), then this prepared PDF (except the placeholder) is hashed, and this hash is to be signed.
